# Do I have a testable angularjs application?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am working in an angularjs application that someone else wrote.  I've been up one side of this application and down the other, adding functionality to it.

I am new to angularjs and also new to unit testing.  I have written over 50 unit tests for this application and as far as I can tell, the major benefit to doing that was finding inconsistencies in the code and fixing them and THEN writing the unit test.

My angular application largely consists of functions like this inside of a single controller:

```
$scope.getDataDoSomethingWithIt = function()
    {
      var url = $scope.endpoint + "my_hard_coded_url";
      methodInAnotherFileThatMakesTheXHRRequest($http, url, "PATCH", mainData.adminToken, mainData.userToken, null, function(response) {
      if (response.status == 200){
            $scope.callSomeOtherMethod();
            $scope.addMessage = "Successfully did something.";
            $scope.isMessage = true;
      }else{

            $scope.addError = "Whoops!  There was an error";
            $scope.isError = true;
        }

      });
    };
```

I'm at a complete loss as to how to meaningfully write a unit test against a method like this.  Mainly because `$scope.endpoint` is set with a `$watch` when `mainData.userToken` is changed.

This is a perfect example of what one of my unit tests look like now:

```
describe('getDataDoSomethingWithIt', function () {
        it('addMessage should not equal null and addError should be empty string.', function () {
            var controller = $controller('myController', { $scope: $scope });
            $scope.getDataDoSomethingWithIt();
            expect($scope.addMessage).not.toBe(null);
            expect($scope.addError).toBe('');
        }); 
    });
```

What purpose does this serve?  What makes a testable angularjs application? If this is a bad unit test, what would make a better one?

Answer (score 0):

I have come a long way since this post.  Endpoint not being set isn't a big deal.  I'm setting that differently now and in a place that is shared across the application.

What I've been trying to understand why the http calls do not get executed when running jasmine tests.

So it seems that any angularjs application is testable.  However, http requests do not get executed by design in testing mode.  It's perfectly clear to me now why that is. We don't want to post and put data into an api in test mode.  The reason being is that UI testing is not supposed to test the backend api.

As the developer writing the test, the beforeEach statement must use $httpBackend and ngMock to mock responses that the application expects.  The test is meant to ensure the application reacts the way you expect it to.